# Prettier and ESlint not working well together

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, prettier

it seems that prettier is not formatting the code like I want to.
My current ESLint config is as follows:

```
 "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "rules": {
      "vue/no-mutating-props": [
        "error",
        {
          "shallowOnly": true
        }
      ],
      "vue/html-self-closing": [
        "error",
        {
          "html": {
            "void": "always"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

and my `.prettierrc` has this rule

```
{
  "printWidth": 120,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": "*.scss",
      "options": {
        "singleQuote": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But whenever I run prettier, the code formats like this

```
<template>
  <pre
    ref="board"
    class="border rounded w-100 text-white bg-dark p-1"
    style="height: 10rem; resize: vertical"
    >{{ robotActionData }}</pre
  >
</template>
```

It's not correct as I get a warning `Expected no line breaks before closing bracket, but 1 line break found` and `Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4 spaces`.

I want prettier to do like this:

```
<template>
  <pre 
    ref="board" 
    class="border rounded w-100 text-white bg-dark p-1" 
    style="height: 10rem; resize: vertical"
  >
    {{ robotActionData }}
  </pre>
</template>
```

How can I adjust prettier in order to format the code like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you didn't use `eslint-plugin-prettier` ?

Install it:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-prettier eslint-config-prettier
```

Also, I recommend to add `plugin:prettier/recommended` in your `.eslintrc` file:

```
"extends": [
  "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
  "eslint:recommended",
  "plugin:prettier/recommended"
],
```

There, both will work fine.